# How many members of Captain Flint's crew are known?

Tags: robert-louis-stevenson, treasure-island

In *Treasure Island*, the most prominent character who never appears on-stage is surely Captain Flint, the notorious pirate captain whose treasure drives the plot. Almost as important as the treasure are several former members of his pirate crew, including:

- Billy Bones, his first mate;
- Long John Silver, his quartermaster;
- Israel Hands, his gunner;
- ...

Quite a number of characters throughout the book are mentioned as having served with Flint. **What is the full list of all known members of Captain Flint's crew?**

<sub>This question is restricted to *Treasure Island* only. Flint crewmembers mentioned in other fiction (e.g. *Peter Pan*) don't count.</sub>

Comment: Wait, Peter Pan is related to Treasure Island? I never knew... the more you know!

Comment: @North *“I am the only man whom Barbecue feared,” [Hook] urged, “and Flint feared Barbecue.”*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### **Billy Bones (first mate)**

Confirmed from his own mouth:

> "I was first mate, I was, old Flint's first mate, and I'm the on'y one as knows the place. He gave it me at Savannah, when he lay a-dying, like as if I was to now, you see."
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 3, "The Black Spot"</sub>

#### Long John Silver (quartermaster)

Confirmed from his own mouth:

> "No, not I,” said Silver. “Flint was cap'n; I was quartermaster, along of my timber leg."
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 11, "What I Heard in the Apple Barrel"</sub>

#### Israel Hands (gunner)

Confirmed explicitly:

> “Israel was Flint's gunner,” said Gray hoarsely.
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 17, "Narrative Continued by the Doctor: The Jolly-boat's Last Trip"</sub>

#### Blind Pew

Strongly suggested by association (although it's *possible* the said "broadside" took place on England's ship, by context in the conversation it seems clearly Flint's):

> "No, not I,” said Silver. “Flint was cap'n; I was quartermaster, along of my timber leg. The same broadside I lost my leg, old Pew lost his deadlights."
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 11, "What I Heard in the Apple Barrel"</sub>

#### Ben Gunn

Confirmed from his own mouth:

> “Now, I'll tell you what,” he went on. “So much I'll tell you, and no more. I were in Flint's ship when he buried the treasure; he and six along—six strong seamen. They was ashore nigh on a week, and us standing off and on in the old Walrus."
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 15, "The Man of the Island"</sub>

#### Tom Morgan

He knew one of Flint's dead crew as an old shipmate up until the time he went ashore with Flint to his death; and he even saw Flint's body immediatedly after his death:

> “I thought so,” cried the cook; “this here is a p'inter. Right up there is our line for the Pole Star and the jolly dollars. But, by thunder! If it don't make me cold inside to think of Flint. This is one of his jokes, and no mistake. Him and these six was alone here; he killed 'em, every man; and this one he hauled here and laid down by compass, shiver my timbers! They're long bones, and the hair's been yellow. Aye, that would be Allardyce. You mind Allardyce, Tom Morgan?”
>
> “Aye, aye,” returned Morgan; “I mind him; he owed me money, he did, and took my knife ashore with him.”
>
> [...]
>
> “No, by gum, it don't,” agreed Silver; “not nat'ral, nor not nice, says you. Great guns! Messmates, but if Flint was living, this would be a hot spot for you and me. Six they were, and six are we; and bones is what they are now.”
>
> “I saw him dead with these here deadlights,” said Morgan. “Billy took me in. There he laid, with penny-pieces on his eyes.”
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 31, "The Treasure-hunt—Flint's Pointer"</sub>

#### George Merry

He knew Flint's voice and Ben Gunn's:

> “Well, that's so,” he said. “You've a head upon your shoulders, John, and no mistake. 'Bout ship, mates! This here crew is on a wrong tack, I do believe. And come to think on it, it was like Flint's voice, I grant you, but not just so clear-away like it, after all. It was liker somebody else's voice now—it was liker—”
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 32, "The Treasure-hunt—The Voice Among the Trees"</sub>

#### Black Dog?

This is never confirmed for sure, but suggested by association. He greets Billy Bones as an old shipmate, he knows Pew and frequents Silver's tavern, and Bones refers to him in the same breath as Flint's crew:

> “Black Dog!” said he.
>
> “And who else?” returned the other, getting more at his ease. “Black Dog as ever was, come for to see his old shipmate Billy, at the Admiral Benbow inn. Ah, Bill, Bill, we have seen a sight of times, us two, since I lost them two talons,” holding up his mutilated hand.
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 2, "Black Dog Appears and Disappears"</sub>

> “Ah! Black Dog,” says he. “He's a bad un; but there's worse that put him on. Now, if I can't get away nohow, and they tip me the black spot, mind you, it's my old sea-chest they're after; you get on a horse—you can, can't you? Well, then, you get on a horse, and go to—well, yes, I will!—to that eternal doctor swab, and tell him to pipe all hands—magistrates and sich—and he'll lay 'em aboard at the Admiral Benbow—all old Flint's crew, man and boy, all on 'em that's left. I was first mate, I was, old Flint's first mate, and I'm the on'y one as knows the place. He gave it me at Savannah, when he lay a-dying, like as if I was to now, you see. But you won't peach unless they get the black spot on me, or unless you see that Black Dog again or a seafaring man with one leg, Jim—him above all.”
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 3, "The Black Spot"</sub>

#### Probably many of the mutineers

Silver says explicitly that many of Flint's old crew are aboard the *Hispaniola*:

> "Where's all England's men now? I dunno. Where's Flint's? Why, most on 'em aboard here, and glad to get the duff—been begging before that, some on 'em."
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 11, "What I Heard in the Apple Barrel"</sub>

Definitely at least two of the unnamed men along with Merry, Morgan, and the others at the end also knew Flint:

> “Yes,” said one, “that's Flint, sure enough. J. F., and a score below, with a clove hitch to it; so he done ever.”
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 29, "The Black Spot Again"</sub>

> “Aye, aye,” returned Morgan; “I mind him; he owed me money, he did, and took my knife ashore with him.”
>
> “Speaking of knives,” said another, “why don't we find his'n lying round? Flint warn't the man to pick a seaman's pocket; and the birds, I guess, would leave it be.”
>
> [...]
>
> “Dead—aye, sure enough he's dead and gone below,” said the fellow with the bandage; “but if ever sperrit walked, it would be Flint's. Dear heart, but he died bad, did Flint!”
>
> “Aye, that he did,” observed another; “now he raged, and now he hollered for the rum, and now he sang. 'Fifteen Men' were his only song, mates; and I tell you true, I never rightly liked to hear it since. It was main hot, and the windy was open, and I hear that old song comin' out as clear as clear—and the death-haul on the man already.”
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 31, "The Treasure-hunt—Flint's Pointer"</sub>

> “I don't feel sharp,” growled Morgan. “Thinkin' o' Flint—I think it were—as done me.”
>
> “Ah, well, my son, you praise your stars he's dead,” said Silver.
>
> “He were an ugly devil,” cried a third pirate with a shudder; “that blue in the face too!”
>
> <sub>-- Chapter 32, "The Treasure-hunt—The Voice Among the Trees"</sub>

These aren't Morgan or Merry, who are referred to by name at this point. They must be at least two of the other three, and probably not Dick who's also usually referred to by name.

One interesting omission is Job Anderson, the boatswain. He's referred to many times, and he seems to be quite senior among the mutineers (on par with Hands and Merry, one step below Silver), but it's never confirmed whether he was a Flint crewman or not.

Answer (score 1):

Allardyce, he was the skeletor compass. And Darby McGraw.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, and take our [tour]! Do you have textual evidence for this? We expect answers here to be backed up so we can make sure they are correct.

Comment: To follow up on @bobble's comment, if you are unable to find textual evidence right now, this answer might be converted to a comment on the question or on the other answer, because the guidelines of this site require answers to be backed up with evidence.  Please see the relevant section in the meta post on [how to write good answers](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/843/289).

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm not sure how I forgot to add sections for Allardyce and Darby McGraw in my answer - some of the quotes I've included even mention them. Maybe because they're not actual characters appearing in the story, only referred to, but the question doesn't specify that, so this is definitely a valid addition to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Jimmy Reynolds. In "Treasure Island" is told, that Flint shoot him, because he insulted a priest on board of the "Walrus".

Comment: Do you have a specific quotation or at least a chapter number for that?

Comment: The name Reynolds doesn't appear anywhere in [the text of *Treasure Island*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/120/120-h/120-h.htm). Are you referring to some adaptation of the story, perhaps?